# spoof OS name in ubuntu for nmap scans

Tags: nmap, ubuntu, fingerprinting

How can I spoof the OS CPE that is reported by nmap?

This is my CPE: `OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3` when scanning with nmap leakage all my OS properties. But I need to change the original information to fake information.

My main goal is that nmap cannot identify the type of operating system.

My open port is 22.